# Double tracking paths in Google Analytics (4)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am not necessarily a pro in GA4 and would like to understand why it seems to display some of my pages twice: once with and once without top level domain at the beginning.

Ex: I am under "Engagement" / "Pages and Screens". In the table I display "Page path and screen class". There are then some pages twice and also differ from page views etc., e.g.

[image]

*(I have replaced the URL for the question here with example.com)*

I have not found any info on this, which is why I would like to ask here. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: install Adswerve's datalayer debugger chrome extension, then go to your site, open JS console, disable your adblockers and reload the page. See what fires. Open the pageview events. See the value of dp dimension. Do it for other pages too. See if the domain ever appears in dp.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :-)

When changing the page I see two commands: 1) event: "nuxtRoute" - sends the current page without TLD as prefix, like /folder/page. Google's "pageView" event got called but aborted, because it gets overwritten by nuxtRoute. So far, so fine. 2) event: "gtm.historyChange-v2" sends the info about the page change (oldUrl, newUrl) BUT with the TLD as prefix like /example.com/folder/page. – followed by another "pageView" event which also got aborted.

So it looks like I need to get the TLD out at the historyChange event?!

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to do some more research to see if we're not currently double tracking. On the one hand we use @nuxtjs/gtm with pageTracking: true and on the other hand gtm.historyChange-v2 is fired

Comment: yes, this mess has to be fixed. You want only one source for analytics events. Looks to me like you're double tracking.

Comment: We have set in the tag manager that NuxtRoute now no longer sends page_view, but is only used for Ads (FB, ...). After one day it looks like the problem with the TLD is solved :-) Thanks again for your tip of the chrome extension.

Comment: The extension is optional really. You could just go to the Network tab, filter by 'collect' and inspect the payload your page sends to the GA endpoint. The extension just makes it easier.